# String manipulation for classification

Tags: python, pandas, classification, text-mining

I have a list of links such as:

```
Website
www.uk_nation.co.uk
www.nation_ny.com
www.unitednation.com
www.nation.of.freedom.es
www.freedom.org
```

and so on.

The above is how the column of my datadrame looks like.
As you can see, they have in common the word '`nation`'.
I would like to label/group them and add one column in my dataframe to respond with a boolean (True/false; e.g. columns: `Nation?` option: `True/False`).

```
Website                       Nation?
www.uk_nation.co.uk           True
www.nation_ny.com             True
www.unitednation.com          True
www.nation.of.freedom.es      True
www.freedom.org               False
```

I would need to do this in order to classify websites in a easier (and possible quicker) way. 
Do you have any suggestions on how to do it?

Any help will be welcome.

Comment: I would like to thank you all of you for your help and answers. I really appreciated it. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is my suggestion:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Website': ['www.uk_nation.co.uk', 
                                'www.nation_ny.com', 
                                'www.unitednation.com', 
                                'www.nation.of.freedom.es', 
                                'www.freedom.org']})

df['Nation?'] = df['Website'].str.contains("nation")
print(df)
```

output:

```
                    Website  Nation?
0       www.uk_nation.co.uk     True
1         www.nation_ny.com     True
2      www.unitednation.com     True
3  www.nation.of.freedom.es     True
4           www.freedom.org    False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `str.contains`

```
df['Nation']=df.Website.str.upper().str.contains('NATION')
0     True
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
Name: Website, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
df['Nation?']= df['website'].apply(lambda x: 'nation' in x.lower())
```